# What is the best way to visualize data that is over 100% capacity

Tags: visualization

I’m trying to visualize some data that is usually under 100% (for example, workload, or activity) but on some occasions it will rise over 100, meaning that the resource has been used too much.

I was thinking on something like the rings Apple use in their activity on Apple Watch, which spins several times before reaching the final value, indicating that you have overdo. The problem is that that type of visualization requires to be dynamic and I need something static (to print on a report)

I can also use a bar chart with a defined boundary if the value exceed 100% but I’m afraid it won’t clearly represent values in small and big numbers.

So is there any type of chart that I’m clearly missing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see small numbers and large numbers on the same chart, you can use a log() scale for the y axis. This will work for bar charts, or other types of charts. Log scaling will show more details than linear over a larger range. Just need to point this out to the user as they may be used to seeing linear scales. For something that changes over time, it can be helpful to show a time based plot, with any data over the limit in red and the data under in green or blue. Also you can add a horizontal line showing the cutoff value.

Example:

Linear vs Log

[image]

Flag with red points including a horizontal line to show the cutoff

[image: plot]